# YouTube AS3 API - Collapse expanding ad after video ends

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api

Im having difficulty collapsing an expanded ad after the video ends. The file is built in FLash CS6, its a YouTube Masthead using the YouTube AS3 API.

What I want, is for the expended file to auto collapse at the end of the video. Ive searched around and found relevant references but Im unsure as to how to "write the code".

Here is what I have tried so far but this does not work...

```
import com.google.ads.studio.innovation.youtube.player.proxy.YTPlayer;

var expanding:Object = StudioClassAccessor.getClass(StudioClassAccessor.CLASS_EXPANDING)["getInstance"]();

function onPlayerStateChange(event:Event):void {
  // Event.data contains the event parameter, which is the new player state
  trace("player state:", Object(event).data);

  // create variable of player state
  var State = ("player state:", Object(event).data);


  if (State == "0")
  expanding.collapse();

}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this and help me understand how this works and show me where ive gone wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you listening for this event? You have an event handler but it doesn't appear there is an event listener. You will need to add an event listener to the instance of the video player.

Comment: Thank you exactly the answer i needed... (im very new to AS3).